# How can I load data from output JSON to fullCalendar events

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, fullcalendar

I need to display the schedule of a classroom when I click the buttons of any classroom into the fullCalendar object.

I've already made it to retrieve the schedules when I select a classroom making an ajax call.

This function triggers when I click any of the classroom buttons.

```
function passVal(id) {
    var calendarioFiltro; //Prepare variable to retrieve DB data

    @foreach($salones as $key => $salon)//This foreach fills a small table of a classroom info
      if(id == '{{$salon->id}}'){
        $('#tb_id').val('{{$salon->id}}');
        $('#tb_nombre').val('{{$salon->nombre}}');
        $('#tb_dimensiones').val('{{$salon->dimensiones}}');
        $('#tb_capacidad').val('{{$salon->capacidad}}');
        $('#tb_costobase').val('{{$salon->costobase}}');
        $('#tb_costomobiliario').val('{{$salon->costo_mobiliario}}');
        $('#tb_descripcion').val('{{$salon->descripcion}}');
      }
    @endforeach

    let url = "salones/seleccionar";//Prepare variables to make an ajax call to my controller and load DB data
    let tb_id = document.getElementById('tb_id').value;//From the small table I have a hidden field to send it to the ajax call for my query
    let parametros;
    let longitud;
    var getEvent = [];

    parametros = {
      "tb_id" : tb_id,//This is the parameter to send
    };

    $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: parametros,
            success: function (data){//Now the data from the query will end up to an array
              calendarioFiltro = data;
              longitud = calendarioFiltro.length;

              var insertEvents = {};
              for(var i = 0;i <= longitud -1;i++)
                {
                  var titulo = calendarioFiltro[i].nombre;
                  var color = calendarioFiltro[i].color;
                  var hora_inicio = calendarioFiltro[i].hora_inicio;
                  var fecha_inicio = calendarioFiltro[i].fecha_inicio;
                  var hora_fin = calendarioFiltro[i].hora_fin;
                  var fecha_fin = calendarioFiltro[i].fecha_fin;

                    insertEvents =//Prepare a JSON format so I can put it into the Events property of my FullCalendar
                    {
                      title : titulo,
                      backgroundColor: color,
                      borderColor: color,
                      startTime: hora_inicio,
                      startRecur : fecha_inicio,
                      endRecur: fecha_fin,
                      endTime: hora_fin,
                    };
                    getEvent.push(insertEvents);//Store all the events in a array format

                };

            }
      });

}
```

Next is the definition of the calendar properties. I've tried many functions but not getting success is a bit frustating.

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid','list'],
    header: {
      left: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'prev,next'
    },
    locale: 'es',
    allDay: false,
  })
  calendar.render();
});
```

Comment: As far as I can see, the events you fetch from the Ajax call are added to an array. After that, nothing happens to them. You need to add them to fullCalendar if you want to display them. Try using https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEventSource

Comment: I tried to use that method.. I wrote calendar.addEventSource(getEvent); before calendar.render(); But events are not rendering when I click my classroom buttons to insert the schedule into de Calendar. I don't know much about JS and DOM so maybe is a JS problem I have?

Comment: You have to add it inside the success function of the Ajax, obviously, otherwise you are adding it to the calendar before it contains any data

Comment: You were right, now what is happening is that the calendar is rendering again everytime I click on a classroom.

Comment: Yes that's what you want to happen. But I will guess that maybe it looks wrong because you never clear the getEvents array before you add new items? It would be better not to have it as a global variable really, I can't see how that's necessary. If you declare it inside the success method then you will get a blank array each time. You might also need the removeEventSource method in fullCalendar if you want to remove the previous results from the calendar itself when you select a new option.

Comment: Oh yeah, the repeated events is not the thing now, so basically when I click it shows a new calendar and not rendering the events on the same calendar.

Comment: From the code you've shown I can't tell how that would be happening. But I think you haven't shown me all of your code, and also it's in two sections so it's out of context. You'd have to give me an example of code which reproduces that issue, otherwise it's hard to help.